# WiFi.h with esp32

Tags: esp32

i am new to esp32 and i want to use WiFi.h in my project but I don't know how to properly download it.

i tried to download the files from this git hub https://github.com/espressif/arduinoesp32/tree/master/libraries/WiFi

but I get this error

```
In file included from sketch\WiFiSTA.h:28:0,

from sketch\WiFi.h:32,

from C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\wifi\wifi.ino:1:

sketch\WiFiGeneric.h:31:39: fatal error: wifi_provisioning/manager.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
error compiling for board ESP32 Wrover Module
```

thx for help

Comment: the WiFi library for esp32 is part of the esp32 Arduino boards package. don't install it separately. put `#include <WiFi.h>` as first in your sketch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cannot compile with this library, it's possible that you have not installed correctly the Arduino board package.
If you install it manually, I recommend reinstalling to do as is explained in their Github: 
https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/docs/arduino-ide/boards_manager.md

In other hand, as Juraj comments,

> the WiFi library for esp32 is part of the esp32 Arduino boards package. don't install it separately

I hope you can compile after following official instructions.